# ZTE H168N in Bridge Mode: Passing ISP IP to secondary AVM Fritz Box

Tags: networking, router, ip, bridge, bridge-router

I have a ZTE H168N device set up as a PTM bridge, providing VDSL2 to my Fritz Box (3390). It works fine, however, my Fritz Box' "ISP IP" is e.g. 100.101.159.155, which I know is not routed and which implies that I cannot reach my box from outside the LAN.

The ZTE device is still accessible via WLAN/LAN, however, internet access is not possible. Also, the Fritz Box is not reachable when connected to the ZTE LAN (however I can see the box connected as LAN, with no internal IP address assigned).

I was wondering how to get the actual ISP IP assigned to the Fritz Box. I was looking through all the menus of the ZTE device, enabling/disabling Firewall, DHCP, NAT, setting LAN as WAN ports, however, it does not change anything. There is no setting like 'IP passthrough'. Does anyone has an idea what setting might help to pass the ISP IP through to the Fritz Box?

Any thought is highly appreciated!